# Set AutoFilter in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Can anyone explain why the first "AutoFilter" statement in the code below continually gives "AutoFilter Method of Range Class Failed" in Excel 2010?

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
shtUSR.Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, VisibleDropDown:=True
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").AutoFilter Field:=2, VisibleDropDown:=True
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True
```

Comment: Which line is erroring exactly? Is it the `ActiveSheet.AutofilterMode = False` line?

Comment: No. It's the first "Autofilter" statement, line 3.

Comment: You are using `activesheet` here, which means that whichever worksheet is assigned to `shtUSR` will need to be the one with the autofilter. Does `shtUSR` have AutoFilter turned on, and does the AutoFiltered range on that sheet exist on `"A1"`?

Comment: @JNevill doesn't matter if there is just a blank cell on "A1" - not error on my excel

Comment: only error I get is the last line of this code

Comment: Perhaps it's a version thing. If I open a brand new workbook in Excel 2007 and try the following: `Sheet1.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, VisibleDropDown:=True` I get the same error as OP. Excel balks unless the `autofilter` method is used on a range that contains an autofilter.

Comment: @JNevill I can never be certain whether autofilter is on or off on a specific sheet. The code will be going through all sheets in the workbook (shtUSR is the current sheet, and it is being selected before this code runs). That's why I was hoping to force autofiltermode off, assign the autofilter to the columns I need, then turn autofiltermode on to force it on.

Comment: Ok, so maybe after turning off autofiltermode, forcefully delete autofilter, then reassign and turn on autofiltering? If that is a shot to try, how do I delete a previously defined autofilter?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious you can't set AutoFilterMode to be True, so this line will error out anyway - if you can get to it!

Comment: @barryleao Thanks. I missed that and it's now gone. Now if only I could have hit that as an error on my own. But still can't get passed the "AutoFilter" statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found it!

Apparently, AutoFilter fails if it can't find any data in the Range.  Try adding values in cells A1 and B1 (and also delete the `ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True` line).  For 'general use' then, to be safe, you would need to do a Find or similar to test for data within the range.

+1 for good Q though.

Comment: Yep! That does it! Thank you! It's been driving me crazy all day!